# Returning a Collection

Tags: java, collections

I need to return a collection which takes the Connection class, but it keeps returning an error saying "cannot find symbol". I lack the understanding on how to return a collection. Takes the parameter of station.

here is the method:

```
@Override
public Collection<Connection> getConnectionsFrom(Station station) {
    return Collection<Connection>(station);
}
```

And here is the Connection class:

```
public class TrainConnection implements Connection {

    double distance;

    private Map<String, Connection> connectionMap;

    public static TrainConnection newConnection = new TrainConnection();

    @Override
    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    @Override
    public Station getStationA() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Station getStationB() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Station getOtherStation(Station station) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, your return in getConnectionsFrom is wrong. Collection is not a specific implementation. So you must instantiate a specific Object that implements collection, then add the station to that collection, and then return it.

Comment: `return Collection<Connection>(station);`what do you think this code does? It's not invoking a constructor, since there is no `new`. If there was, Collection is an interface, so you can't construct one. You can only construct instances of concrete classes that implement the interface (like ArrayList or HashSet, for example)

Comment: Another thing I can't see in your code is what `Station` is. You specify you are going to return a `Collection<Connection>`, but instead you try to instantiate the collection with a `Station`.

Comment: @CacheStaheli, good observation!

Comment: This class is really bad. There are a lot of problems with it, so I don't know if we will be able to help you solve the Collection problem. I can't actually figure out how `Station` and `Connection` are related. And why does the `TrainConnection` have a map of other connections? Does the connection _have_ other connections? Did you mean it has stations?

Answer (score 0):

As an example of how to fix the getConnectionsFrom, making the assumption it was actually supposed to return Collection as pointed out above.

```
public Collection<Station> getConnectionsFrom(Station station)
{
   Collection<Station> connections = new ArrayList<>();
   connections.add(station);
   return connections;
}
```

However, be aware that a **new** Collection would be created each time. You need to be more specific about the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: I would also add that unless it's noted in other code we don't have, a `Station` is not a `Connection`, so you can't `add` it

Comment: This won't work as @CacheStaheli pointed out, im assuming he wants the connections inside station's connectionMap, in which case he needs to add them individually by looping through the map

Comment: @CacheStaheli, you are absolutely correct. I changed the return type.

Comment: @GordonAllocman, you may be correct about the desired functionality. Though looping through the Map doesn't give a Station, as the key is a String.

Comment: @KevinO what I meant by that was to grab all Connection values stored in the map (I know this is fairly simple in c# but I haven't done much with maps in java) and put then in a List of some sort, which is what I interpreted the asker's purpose to be

Comment: @GordonAllocman, it is unclear (to me) that the `getConnectionsFrom` is in the `TrainConnection` class. And we do not currently have a definition for the `Station` class, so I do not know if there is a Map in that class to iterate.

Comment: @KevinO wow I misread that and thought the connection class was the Station class, since it would make much more sense to post code for that over connection. My mistake

Comment: @KevinO the return line throws the error - Incompatible types: Collection <Station> cannot be converted to Collection<Connection>                                                                                  (this is what I am attempting to return: a Collection containing all the connections that start or end at the specified station)